# sbt runs on command line but not VS code

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt

So I've been trying to run scala on vs code for nearly a week now with no luck. We have been recommended to use sbt to run our programs.

I'm running java version "1.8.0_301" on my build environment.

when running the sbt command on vs code I get project loading failed with this error:

```
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
```

What's weird is that I can run sbt on my command line with no problems!
I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTKYq.jpg (link to the vs code window after failed loading and scala running on terminal)

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that occurs with outdated sbt versions. Upgrade to the latest sbt version and you should be fine.
Unfortunately I don't recall exactly when this was fixed.